# Pass information from one view model to another

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

[image]

I am using the M-V-VM architectural pattern.

I want my program to have two views, **View A** and **View B**. I start the program with **View A**. **View B** is shown by the program when I double click an item in **View A**.

How should I structure my program such that I can achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have one ViewModel like :

- ParentViewModel

  - ChildViewModel1

    - IsVisible
    - A Command that toggles ChildViewModel's IsVisible property
  - ChildViewModel2

    - IsVisible

and View like :

- ParentView

  - ViewPart1

    - Visibility bound to ChildViewModel1.IsVisible (use BooleanToVisibilityConverter)
    - A button bound to Command that toggles Visibility
  - ViewPart2

    - Visibility bound to ChildViewModel1.IsVisible (use BooleanToVisibilityConverter)

This should solve your problem.

Comment: Are objects that are not visible still kept in memory?

Comment: Yes. Like you said, they are just not visible.

Comment: Another question, what is the role of ChildViewModel2?

Comment: When you compose your view of multiple small views, for example, in a window we have a title bar, content and a status bar, you create view models for each of the view. In above example, I demonstrated with a view composed of two other views. That in turn will need a main view model with two child view models mapping to appropriate views.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the **BookLibrary** sample application of the **[WPF Application Framework (WAF)](http://waf.codeplex.com)**. It shows a master/detail view with two separate Views and two separate ViewModels. Additionally, it has a modal dialog inclusive an own ViewModel for the "Lend To" operation which is connected to the selected book.